# determine the spark job duration in databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to understand what time will be required for my spark job to be completed. What I am doing is copying my json files in an azure blob storage to a delta lake table in databricks. below is the code I have used. the json file size is approx 100 TB and the job has been running for 15 hrs now. Is there a way I can determine the duration and what I can do to improve it?

```
table_name= "main.auditlogs.Customer_Logs"
checkpoint_path = "/mnt/_checkpoint"
file_path ="/mnt/topics/audit-logs"
schema = "authenticationMechanism STRING,authenticationMechanismId STRING,xHeaderFields ARRAY<STRUCT<key: STRING, value: STRING>>"
(spark.readStream
  .format("cloudFiles")
  .option("cloudFiles.format", "json")
  .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", checkpoint_path)
  .option("ignoreMissingFiles", "true")  
  .schema(schema)  
  .load(file_path)  
  .writeStream
  .option("mergeSchema", "true")
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path)
  .trigger(availableNow=True)
  .toTable(table_name))
```

Comment: is a it a single JSON file? is it compressed? if yes, what algorithm? Can you split file into multiple files?

Comment: no its multiple json files.. each file has multiple json lines.. i am reading these files and putting it in one delta table

Comment: is there a way to identify how many jobs or stages are left

Comment: Also a follow up question what will happen if I cancel the job which is running..will all the files it has written to the table will go away? since it is autoloader..isnt it suppose to take from where it left?

Comment: You need to check how many batches are already processed. When you cancel, then it will cancel only latest not written batch...